# SonarQube Server Log shows GC overhead limit exceeded and TERM trapped Shutting down

Tags: java, sonarqube

**Server Environment:** `SonarQube – 6.7.7 and Openjdk version - "1.8.0_222"`

**Problem:** Suddenly our sonarqube web application started hanging. From sonar.log found the below errors.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Dumping heap to java_pid21155.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [10548624193 bytes in 50.277 secs]
TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
```

To fix the same. Increased values for Web Server, Compute Engine and Elastic Search values in `$SONAR_HOME/conf/sonar.properties` file.

**Web Server:**

```
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx8G -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

**Compute Engine:**

```
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx8G -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

**Elastic Search:**

```
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xms6G -Xmx6G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

But didn’t work. Then found service was running with jre path - /`usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java`. So updated below in `$SONAR_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf` file

```
wrapper.java.command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/bin/java
```

But after service restart still it runs jre/bin/java only. Then i have configured `JAVA_HOME` pointing to my JDK but still it is running through `jre`, Any inputs would help to address the problem.

Comment: did you edit PATH variable ? i.e.: `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Yes I have included this variable in my account's .bashrc file.

Comment: anyway, it doesn't matter if it's jdk or jre, actually jdk uses jre for running. Here the important part are the options to assign more memory: javaOpts=-Xmx8G -Xms512m

Comment: Ok then I will increase more memory to javaOpts=-Xmx2G -Xms12G and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by increasing the -Xms512m value to -Xms4G parameters of Web server, Compute Engine and Elastic search.